# Coloring the diagonal in a 2d array angular matrix

Tags: angularjs, matrix, multidimensional-array, html-table

I'm trying to color the diagonal in my given square matrix `$scope.matrix`.

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="row in matrix track by $index">
  <td>{{matrix[$index].title}}</td>
  <td>{{$index+1}}</th> <!-- # on left side of table as info -->
  <td ng-repeat="column in row track by $index">{{column.itemData}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Two columns in the beginning are inserted with information.
The output should thus be:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 | ColA | ColB | ColC |
| dim  | 1    | x    |      |      |
| dim  | 2    |      | x    |      |
| dim  | 3    |      |      | x    |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

With the 'x' marked cells colored. I have no clue how to do it with `$index` or ng-repeat. Its ridiculous but I don't know how.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you want to color x marked columns only?

Comment: just the cells which are in diagonale (except the 2 first columns), so yes just the x. the above is just an example dataset. of course its bigger
I need something like ng-if to add a class for coloring, thats for sure. But i'm struggling to detect if i'm on the diagonale or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, row) in matrix track by $index">
  <td>{{matrix[$index].title}}</td>
  <td>{{$index+1}}</th> <!-- # on left side of table as info -->
  <td ng-class="{'class-name': key == $index}" ng-repeat="column in row track by $index">{{column.itemData}}</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
.class-name{
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Works flawlessly and learned about conditionally applying classes as well as indexing! Thanks, you made my day